# Replacing <appname>.exe.config with an AfterBuild doesn't apply to <appname>.vshost.exe.config

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, app-config

We're using an `AfterBuild` target in the `vbproj` to replace the config file depending on the selected configuration :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">
  <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
</Target>
```

As an example, let's say we have 3 configurations : Debug, Test, Release. Debug is the local debugging configuration. Test is a pre-production environment used for user-acceptance tests. Release is our production environment.

In the `App.config` file, we store the configuration for our Release environment. In the `Debug.config` file, we store the configuration for our local debugging needs. In the `Test.config` file, we store the configuration for our user-acceptance environment.

The goal of the `AfterBuild` target is to replace the Release configuration (`App.config`) when building/executing with the Debug configuration (`Debug.config`) or the Test configuration (`Test.config`).

Everything works as intended when we publish the application (Release, `App.config`) or if we build the application and launch the `bin\<appname>.exe` (Debug or Test).

However, if we Start the application from Visual Studio, with the Visual Studio hosting process, the correct configuration is copied to `bin\<appname>.exe.config`, but it seems that Visual Studio doesn't copy the correct configuration to `bin\<appname>.vshost.exe.config`. We tried cleaning the solution, performing a Rebuild *before* debugging, manually deleting the `bin\<appname>.vshost.exe.config` file before launching, but it seems that the hosting process always copies the configuration from the default `App.config` file. The same problem happens whether we try to Start with the Debug configuration or the Test configuration.

To add to the confusion, we created multiple test projects, using the same `AfterBuild` target, and some of them work correctly, others don't. All projects are using .Net Framework 4.5.1, but we also reproduced the problem with .Net 4.5. It doesn't seem to be caused by the project type, since we're able to reproduce the issue with a Console Application as well as a Windows Forms Application.

What could be causing the problem?

Alternatively, could we use another solution to manage the configuration for each of our environment?

**Notes**

- We use the default App.config file for our Release environment
  because ClickOnce doesn't seem to support AfterBuild targets.
- We use Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop, so we can't use any plugin like SlowCheetah.

Comment: Just an idea to work with. Using the PreBuild event and copying the required config over the app.config leaving VS do its usual work?

Comment: interested to see if someone knows how to do this... we tried, and failed, and resorted to manually changing config files for running inside VS.

Comment: Hard to see why you don't just add another `<Copy>` command.  Or simpler yet, just turn of the hosting process option.

Comment: @HansPassant : I'm pretty sure the config is copied on launch, not on build. If we added another `<Copy>` command, it wouldn't be executed on launch anyway.

Comment: @Steve : We tried the approach you suggested, and we still observe the same behavior. If we switch the configuration from Release to Debug, the App.config contains the correct parameters for the selected configuration (Debug), but the hosting process still uses the previous configuration (Release)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Steve's suggestion, we moved the logic to the `BeforeCompile` target, specifying to replace the `App.config` depending on the selected configuration :

```
<Target Name="BeforeCompile">
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)App.config" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)$(Configuration).config" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)App.config" />
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </Copy>
</Target>
```

It wouldn't replace the file every time, and when it did, it didn't necessarily apply to the `<appname>.vshost.exe.config` file. We stumbled on another answer which guided us on the right path : [Can Visual Studio automatically adjust the name of other file as it does with app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994244/can-visual-studio-automatically-adjust-the-name-of-other-file-as-it-does-with-ap)

Adding the following `<Copy>` command, we achieved the desired behavior :

```
<!--
Copy the application's .config file, if any.
Not using SkipUnchangedFiles="true" because the application may want to change
the app.config and not have an incremental build replace it.
-->
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)"
    DestinationFiles="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath->'$(OutDir)%(TargetPath)')"
    OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
    Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
    RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
    UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForAdditionalFilesIfPossible)"
    >

    <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>

</Copy>
```

We now have a config file for each configuration (`Debug.config`, `Test.config`, `Release.config`). Visual Studio replaces the `App.config` file with the correct one on each build/launch. The resulting `<appname>.vshost.exe.config` file contains the correct parameters.

**Bonus**

The underlying benefit with this solution is that we have one config file per configuration, so we can update the `.vbproj` file and replace, for example,

```
<None Include="Debug.config" />
<None Include="Release.config" />
```

with

```
<None Include="Debug.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Release.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

All config files will be grouped under the main `App.config` file in Visual Studio :
[image]

Comment: thx for the one with `DependentUpon` i wouldn't have thought on this one.

Comment: Having same problem, where did you add your copy command? in <Target Name="BeforeCompile">?

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to disable VisualStudio hosting process.

Remove the check mark in:

```
Project -> Preferences -> Debug -> Enable Visual Studio hosting process
```

This stops Visual Studio from overwriting the *config file.